# Date range time query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query MySQL using a start and end date range. At the moment my variables are:

```
$begin = $_POST['begin'];
$begin = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($begin));
$end = $_POST['end'];
$end = date('Y/m/d H:i:s',strtotime($end));
```

`strtotime($begin)` produces an argeeable timestamp '00:00:00'. However I'd like `strtotime($end)` to output '11:59:59' so that users can query a particular day using the date range in my form. Can someone kindly demonstrate how to set to time as '23:59:59', bearing in mind I wish to use the `$end` date variable from my form?

My query from PHP is:

> "SELECT OrderId, Qty, Del, Timestamp FROM Orders  WHERE Timestamp
>   BETWEEN '$begin' AND '$end'";

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean `11:59:59`, not `23:59:59`?

Comment: Why 11:59:59 and not 23:59:59?  What data is provided for $_POST['begin'] and $_POST['end']?  can you show samples of the DB query and sort of data you would be querying? I ask these questions as chances are you don't need to create some artificial end date, you just need to query the DB appropriately.

Comment: My apologies, I did mean 23:59:59. $_POST['begin'] and $_POST['end'] are full dates (i.e. 02/07/2013). However, I'm querying a timestamp.

Comment: @Mike Brant Thanks for your help. I've updated my original question. Is using `$end = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($end) + 86400 - 1);` a good solution? It works, but is there an easier way around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strtotime simply produces an integer timestamp, so you could do

```
$end = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($end) + 86400 - 1);
```

add a day to get "tomorrow", then remove one second to get the moment before midnight of the day you started on.

Or simpler yet:

```
$end = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($end)) . ' 11:59:59';
```

produce the appropriate date, then tack on the time portion manually yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hard-code the time, just concatenate it:

```
$end = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($end)) . ' 11:59:59';
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` returns a timestamp. you can add 86399 (1 day - 1 second)

or you can use the strtotime + syntax so `strtotime($end . "+ 23 hours")`

or if there is no time info in the variable you can just add it yourself `strtotime($end . "+ 23:59")`

your other option is to convert to a datetime object which gives much more flexibility